# how to change HtmlWeb encoding

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, html-agility-pack

I am trying to load a webpage for a windows phone app using the htmlagilitypack, the problem is that the encoding is iso-8859-7 and the htmlWeb class loads the page as a utf.
I try to solve this with the following code:

```
 public auditPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            HtmlWeb hwWeb = new HtmlWeb();
            hwWeb = new HtmlWeb
            {
                AutoDetectEncoding = false,
                OverrideEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-7"),
            };
           HtmlWeb.LoadAsync("url", HtmlWeb_load);
        }
```

But i get the following errors : 
'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb' does not contain a definition for 'OverrideEncoding'
'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb' does not contain a definition for 'AutoDetectEncoding'. What can i do to encode the html page correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

Autodetectencoding was added in one of the latest versions and is maybe not available in the version you've added to the project. [Version 1.4.0 has this property](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/94773#1096541).

See also:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/b2733aa5-99dc-4bcc-a3b8-ea0754f494e0/

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way here is not to use `HtmlWeb`. It seems it has some troubles with correct stream encoding detection.

But you could do it manually e.g. by using [`WebClient.OpenReadAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144211.aspx), and then `HtmlDocument.Load` method which accepts stream encoding as a second parameter like this:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.OpenReadCompleted += (sender, e) =>
{
    doc.Load(e.Result, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-7"));
    e.Result.Close();
};
client.OpenReadAsync(url);
```